# error in installing python module

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, biopython

I am trying to install a python module called biopython using pip install biopython and setup.py install but getting following error.

```
 error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Comment: http://springflex.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-fix-valueerror-when-trying-to.html

Answer (score 2):

You can get a pre-compiled `.whl` of Biopython [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#biopython) at Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows repository. The page also contains many other packages, so I recommend looking there first before attempting to install from scratch.

Comment: @ MattDMo.  Thank you for the information.  Should I directly get from there?